# Why keyboard IRQ number is exactly 1?

Tags: x86, x86-64, driver, osdev

I just very much wonder if this is the number set to stone,
Is it standard that everyone must follow?

As I can understand it's caused by the fact that it's connected to first interrupt line in the PIC.
But we could make it to be connected to any.

Is there a way to probe PIC and match with an appropriate device?
If so does it common practice?

PS: Sorry the question on it's self shows my newbie knowledge.

Comment: It is simply what IBM's designers settled upon when creating the original PC. Clones had to copy such details in order to be compatible. I suppose for modern systems now that BIOS is going away (or already has) it could be something different.

Comment: Related: [How does the BIOS distinguish Interrupt(08h-12h) from INT instructions, vs. actual exceptions inside the CPU?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/24552) - IBM didn't follow Intel's documentation that reserved the first 32 interrupt numbers for CPU exceptions. But that's about software interrupts like `int 10h`, not external IRQ numbers which get mapped to different interrupt vectors.

Comment: Also related: https://wiki.osdev.org/Interrupts has a table of IBM-PC interrupt numbers.